# Single sign on for applications whose front end developed using the java script, html, css technologies

Tags: javascript, oracle, jet

I am using oracle JET library to develop front end applications. I would like to implement SSO for this application. There is one authentication server, there we provide user details, if success, the server redirects the request to my application. How can I read the request object in my application.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have developed front end application and the rest web services for data services. Now we have a authenticated server. We register the context root in authenticated server for the front end application. We provide the user details in authenticated server, if success, it forwards the request to front end application with user details in the request object. Here how can I read the request object headers.